# adding a button on an Echo that produces rows

Tags: php

i've made an echo that produces a table in the correct format based on the data its echo'ing. However on the same line of each echo, i'd like to add a button that is on the same row, and linked to that row of data.

```
echo "\t<tr><td>". $row["Title"]. " </td><td> ". 
$row["PerfDate"]. " </td><td> " . $row["PerfTime"] . " </td><td> " . $row[button] . "</td> 
</tr>\n" ;
```

above is the echo, there are three "rows" being echoed out and being placed correctly into a table. How do i place a button in there too so that each time it produces a new set, that set has a button linked to it?

Many thanks

Comment: If I get you right, you mean the button should have an unique identifier for that specific row, is that correct? In this case, you can work with the html attribute "id", for example: `<button name="rowbutton" id="'.$row['Title'].'">BUTTON</button>`

Comment: @KerimYagmurcu Hello! thank you so much for the help, let me try and update my code on the post to show you how i mean. i added in a .$row button on the post, i just simply need one there if that makes sense, so it echos it out for each set of data

Comment: This needs to be a client-side behavior, right?  Where is your javascript attempt?

Comment: @mickmackusa hello, thank you for replying. I've never used javascript and i didn't know that it must be done this way? the echo's are displaying contents from an SQL table, and im trying to add it so that each time an echo line is done, a button that is linked to that line of data appears next to the data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    echo '<tr>
    <td>'.$row['Title'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['PerfDate'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['PerfTime'].'</td>
    <td><button onClick="doit()" name="'.$row['Title'].'" value="'.$row['Title'].'"></button></td> 
    </tr>
    <script>
      function doit(){
        window.open("https://www.w3schools.com"); 
      }
    </script>';
```

updated :) || updated again :)

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected ''.$row['' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' line 64 ` it throws this error for the line with the button on

Comment: this is displaying a button now thank you so much! How am i able to make it so the button has text / does an action when clicked? would that be in the same lines of code?